# AngularJS REST response not available

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse, rest

I'm new to the development with RESTful services and AngularJS. After about 10hours of searching for a solution, including googles search results and tons of threads here I decided to post just another question.

First of all: My environment contains several components. The first one is my laptop. I'm running Eclipse with AngularJS plugins and developing the frontend locally with eclipse and its integrated browser/view & editor.

The second component is my desktop computer. This is the point where I provide the rest api / interfaces to interact with. (The backend part of my application with jersey and java ee, running on the local tomcat7 with eclipse).
The last point is a tomcat server, running in a virtual environment on my esxi. This should be the point where both projects come together later on.

My problem is the following. I want to retrieve the data from the jersey backend. In detail: I retrieve the menu entries from database and show them in navigation bar of the app: [MenuBar working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpBnm.png)

This is is awesome! yippie! it works... locally in my eclipse browser (AND when I open the path locally with safari browser).

It does not work, when I publish the index.html and the app.js to my server (apache and tomcat instances. Both not displaying the menu!)

The JSON which is returned from the backend:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Administration",
    "entries": [
        {
            "name": "UserList",
            "url": "userlist"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ticket",
            "url": "ticketlist"
        },
        {
            "name": "MenuList",
            "url": "menulist"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "CMDB",
    "entries": [
        {
            "name": "Configuration Items",
            "url": "cilist"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I've validated the result with http://jsonlint.com and it's valid!

Here is my angularJS controller:

```html
app.controller('AController', function ($scope, navBarFcty){
 $scope.menulist = navBarFcty.query();
});

app.factory('navBarFcty', function($resource){
 return $resource('http://myserverIP/webportal/rest/menu/get', {},
   {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true} }
   );
});

//OLD Controller 
app.controller('AControllerOld', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://myserverIP/webportal/rest/menu/get').
        success(function(data){
            $scope.menulist = data;
        });

});
```

But both are working just locally with my eclipse browser. As you can see I've tried several things to debug my problem. Even I dealed with the crossdomain.xml on my tomcat server, but still  no success.

Before I finish my question here is the source for displaying the entries in frontend:

```html
<li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="category in menulist">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{category.name}}
</a></li>
```

Comment: Using your old controller, did you add a console.log(data) after .success to check if the data was coming through?

Comment: Press F12 in your chrome browser and see what the network/console tabs are displaying.  I think it's a cross domain issue but I can't tell from your description.

Comment: its not CORS problem, even the index html is not deployed ?  Check your tomcat logs on the server.

Comment: Use your old controller and after succes write console.log(data); you can see your errors with press F12.